# Calculate VAT when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function where the total amount is displayed when the relevant price is selected however i would like to make an IF where if after all prices are selected and then checked VAT to multiply by 1.2 the total.

```
function show_payment_values() {
    $(".sum").show();
    final_price = (register_price + optional_price);
    if ($("#vat").is(":checked")) {
        $(".payment_value").text(final_price * 1.2 + "лв.");
        $("#payment_value").val(final_price * 1.2);
        $("#other_value").val(optional_price);
    } else {
        $(".payment_value").text(final_price + "лв.");
        $("#payment_value").val(final_price );
        $("#other_value").val(optional_price);
    }
    if (final_price == 0) {
        $(".vat input").removeAttr("required", "required");
        $("#vat").prop('checked', false);
        $("input[name='paymentMethod']").removeAttr("required", "required");
    } else {
        $("input[name='paymentMethod']").attr("required", "required");
    }
}
```

I will appreciate if you have any ideas, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call the show_payment_values() function on change of(#vat checkbox element) 

$('#vat').change(function() {
        show_payment_values(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it on [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

```js
$('#vat').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".payment_value").text(final_price * 1.2 + "лв.");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="">

    <input type="checkbox" value="on" name="vat" id="vat">
</form>
<button onClick="fun();"></button>
<script>

//sample  function 
function fun(){
    var vatcheck = document.getElementById("vat").checked;
      if (vatcheck=="true") {
            alert("hai");  
      }
      else{
         alert(vatcheck);  
      }
}
//your code use this function and add a an id vat  to checkbox
function show_payment_values() {
    $(".sum").show();
    final_price = (register_price + optional_price);
    var vatcheck = document.getElementById("vat").checked;
    if (vatcheck=="true") {
        $(".payment_value").text(final_price * 1.2 + "лв.");
        $("#payment_value").val(final_price * 1.2);
        $("#other_value").val(optional_price);
    } else {
        $(".payment_value").text(final_price + "лв.");
        $("#payment_value").val(final_price );
        $("#other_value").val(optional_price);
    }
    if (final_price == 0) {
        $(".vat input").removeAttr("required", "required");
         document.getElementById("vat").checked= false;
        $("input[name='paymentMethod']").removeAttr("required", "required");
    } else {
        $("input[name='paymentMethod']").attr("required", "required");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```